# Definição recursiva da função pré-defenida EnumFromThenTo

Tags: haskell

Como definir recursivamente a função EnumFromThenTo

Comment: A ideia desse site é ajudar com a solução, tentou algo?

Answer (score 0):

A função `enumFromThenTo` retorna uma sequência com início no primeiro parâmetro da função (na maioria dos casos), seguido dos seus sucessores de acordo com uma determinada distância (diferença entre o primeiro e o segundo parâmetro) até atingir o final da sequência (terceiro parâmetro da função).

```
Entrada: enumFromThenTo 1 3 7 
Saída: [1,3,5,7]

Entrada: enumFromThenTo 2 6 8 
Saída: [2,6]
```

Fica aqui um exemplo de uma implementação recursiva, para o universo dos números inteiros:

```
myEnumFromThenTo:: Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
myEnumFromThenTo p d u 
    | d == 0 = []
    | u < d = [p]
    | otherwise = p : myEnumFromThenTo d (2 * d - p) u
```

Note que isto é apenas um exemplo para os números inteiros. A função `enumFromThenTo` da biblioteca `Prelude`, com assinatura `enumFromThenTo :: Enum a => a -> a -> a -> [a]` pode ser aplicada aos tipo da class Enum, pelo que a sua definição é bastante mais complexa.

<sub>A implementação da função generic fica como exercicio :)</sub>